# Spring java 11 getting IllegalArgumentException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Spring 5.1 java 11 getting ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader**

- Spring : 5.1.10
- Jdk : Correto 11
- Spring Boot : 2.1.9.RELEASE

Code causing issue:

```
@Async(value = AsynchConfig.INDEXING_EVENT_EXECUTOR)
   @EventListener
   public void handleFeedEventLogSave(LogFeedEvent lfe)
   {

      eventService.log(lfe.setAppId(appId)
            .toFeedEvent()
            .setLinks(linkProvider.getLinksForStep(lfe.getFileId(), lfe.getStep(), lfe.getStatus())));
      LOG.debug("Event Log event triggered");
   }
```

Stack trace :

```
o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler - Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void org.foo.event.LogFeedEventProcessor.handleFeedEventLogSave(org.foo.event.LogFeedEvent)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.ensureVisible(Proxy.java:858)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.validateProxyInterfaces(Proxy.java:681)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:627)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:123)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:113)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils.getProxyWithInterceptor(DummyInvocationUtils.java:174)
        at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils.access$000(DummyInvocationUtils.java:44)
        at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils$InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor.intercept(DummyInvocationUtils.java:112)
        at org.foo.web.FlowResource$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17824eae.flow(<generated>)
        at org.foo.LinkProviderImpl.getFlowInfoLink(LinkProviderImpl.java:52)
        at org.foo.LinkProviderImpl.getLinksForStep(LinkProviderImpl.java:60)
        at org.foo.event.LogFeedEventProcessor.handleFeedEventLogSave(LogFeedEventProcessor.java:56)
        at org.foo.event.LogFeedEventProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8800fbd.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceAsyncAspect.traceBackgroundThread(TraceAsyncAspect.java:67)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor386.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceCallable.call(TraceCallable.java:70)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code itself?

Comment: sure @SemyonKirekov added

Comment: The OSS support period for Spring Boot 2.1 and Spring Framework 5.1 has elapsed. You should upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.x or 2.6.x (and Framework 5.3.x) as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson so there is no other alternative as that is a big jump . We will try 2.3 though